# Recode a pandas.Series containing 0, 1, and NaN to False, True, and NaN

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a Series with NaNs:

```
pd.Series([0, 1, None, 1])
```

I want to transform this to be equal to:

```
pd.Series([False, True, None, True])
```

You'd think `x == 1` would suffice, but instead, this returns:

```
pd.Series([False, True, False, True])
```

where the null value has become `False`. This is because `np.nan == 1` returns `False`, rather than `None` or `np.nan` as in R.

Is there a nice, vectorized way to get what I want?

Comment: `data = data.astype(bool)` should give what you want.

Comment: @MaxNoe No, that changes NaNs to `True` (at least in pandas 0.17.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series([0, 1, None, 1])

print x.map({1: True, 0: False})

0    False
1     True
2      NaN
3     True
dtype: object
```

Comment: `x.map({0: False, 1: True})` alone seems to suffice. Perhaps that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use where:

```
In [11]: (s == 1).where(s.notnull(), np.nan)
Out[11]:
0     0
1     1
2   NaN
3     1
dtype: float64
```

Note: the True and False have been cast to float as 0 and 1.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't this just bring me back to square one? 0s and 1s are what I'm trying to replace.

Comment: @Kodiologist If you have 2s and 3s in there, they'll also be set to false -> 0.

Comment: @Kodiologist also there's no boolean (or int) type with nan, you'd have to use object which is less efficient/slower than float.